# ¿Cómo puedo guardar un archivo .txt de más de mil caracteres en una variable array? Al momento de imprimir, sólo imprime la mitad del archivo

Tags: c

`maze-4.txt` es el archivo que no lee.

```
int main(){

    FILE * flujos = fopen("maze-4.txt","rb");
    if (flujos == NULL){
        perror("Error");
        return 1;
    }
    int i=0;
    char caracter;
    char arr[i];
```

En el `while` se imprime uno a uno los caracteres mientras los guarda en un array.

```
    while(feof(flujos) == NULL){
        fscanf(flujos,"%c",&caracter);
        printf("%c",caracter);
        arr[i] =caracter;
        i++;

    }
    fclose(flujos);
    printf("\nSuccessful\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con "*el archivo que no lee*"? ¿Cuál es el comportamiento que ves y cuál es el que esperabas?

Comment: Veo que creas un array `char arr[i]`, donde dos líneas antes inicializas `int i=0`. Te recomiendo crear el tamaño del array (si sabes qué dimensiones va a tener) de forma que ya indicas el tamaño necesario en memoria: `char arr[1000]`

Answer (score 0):

He solucionado el problema, pero ahora, al momento de verificar si se ha guardado correctamente en el array, me imprime solo símbolos.

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

```
FILE * flujos = fopen("maze-3.txt","rb");
if (flujos == NULL){
    perror("Error");
    return 1;

}
int i;
char caracter;
char arr[i];
arr[i] =caracter;
while(feof(flujos) == NULL){
    i=0;
    fscanf(flujos,"%c",&caracter);
    printf("%c",caracter);
    arr[i] =caracter;
    i++;
}
```

> Aquí, arr[2], me retorna @ y arr[1] me retorna !

```
printf("%c",arr[2]);
fclose(flujos);


return 0;
```

}

> Corrección: maze-4.txt se lee correctamente, solo que no se leía completo (Solucionado).